# AWS Lambda, python and AWS SFTP Stack

Tags: database, csv, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, sftp

I have an AWS FTP running and I'm sending files to it, I'm sending CSV files and I want to import all my .CSV to my db.

My db is running on an EC2 instance.

stack:
AWS SFT (send files CSV) --> S3 ---> (trigger lambda on file upload) ---> Lambda [python: get csv and import into db]

I was wondering if this is possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

1. Add a trigger in your Lambda to the S3 bucket that you'll send the CSV files.

[image]

2. Ensure that the Lambda has the permissions to get an object in the S3 bucket and can connect to the EC2 instance.
3. Create your code to read the object content from S3 when it triggers the Lambda.

[image]

4. And you are ready to create your automation.

[image]

My sample code:

```py
import boto3
    
    
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event.get("Records", []):
        bucket_name = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        object_key  = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
            
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)
        content  = response["Body"].read()
```